# Alternatives to many nested for loops?

Tags: julia

for scientific purposes I have to evaluate a function of 8 parameters over and over again for these parameters that take values in some ranges.

Is there something more clever (and better performing) than a straightforward code with 8 nested for loops?

thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Iterators.product`, which combine multiple iterators, like this:

```
julia> for (i, j, k) in Iterators.product(1:2, 5:6, -2:-1)
       println("hi, $i, $j and $(k)!")
       end
hi, 1, 5 and -2!
hi, 2, 5 and -2!
hi, 1, 6 and -2!
hi, 2, 6 and -2!
hi, 1, 5 and -1!
hi, 2, 5 and -1!
hi, 1, 6 and -1!
hi, 2, 6 and -1!
```

You can also return it as a tuple, that you index into, like this:

```
julia> for K in Iterators.product(1:2, 5:6, -2:-1)
       println("hi, $(K[1]), $(K[2]) and $(K[3])!")
       end
hi, 1, 5 and -2!
hi, 2, 5 and -2!
hi, 1, 6 and -2!
hi, 2, 6 and -2!
hi, 1, 5 and -1!
hi, 2, 5 and -1!
hi, 1, 6 and -1!
hi, 2, 6 and -1!
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for the suggestion. I made a new version of the code which uses Iterators.product but I find that it is consistently slower than the version with nested for loops. Any idea why?

Comment: Hard to say without an MWE.

Comment: `Iterators.jl` is now `IterTools.jl`. Trying doing the same thing using the newer package.

Comment: I don't think so. The external package `Iterators.jl` was renamed to `IterTools.jl` because a lot of iterator functionality was moved to `Base.Iterators`. `Base.Iterators` and `IterTools.jl` exist side-by-side, but the latter is an external package.

Comment: just to clarify, I am using Base.Iterators. I will post a working example ASAP.

Comment: @DNF: here are the files I have been using. [Nested for loops](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fk0xj2efha6ndzt/scan_nested_for.jl?dl=0), [iterator version](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qatee24po1x54qw/scan_iterator.jl?dl=0)

Comment: I won't have much time to look at this. But I think this will work better as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/), since Dropbox cannot preview .jl files.